# How to apply filter in WHERE clause for Unnested Value in Big Query without using Inner query or CTE?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, filtering

I want to filter by the output of unnest but having an error

> Unrecognized name: customer_id at [23:73]

```
 SELECT
          fullVisitorId,
          totals.transactionRevenue,

       (SELECT 
    MAX(
    IF
      (index=3,
        value,
        NULL))
  FROM
    UNNEST(hits.customDimensions)) AS customer_id

 FROM `XXXX.google_analytics.google_analytics_fact` as GA,
 UNNEST(GA.hits) as hits
  WHERE customer_id IS NOT NULL
```

I can filter the output with inner query or CTE but I am looking for a way to apply filter without using them.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it doesn't exist in the table - `SELECT` gets executed last.

But you can use subqueries in `WHERE`

```sql
 SELECT
   fullVisitorId,
   totals.transactionRevenue,

   (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) WHERE index=3) AS customer_id

 FROM `XXXX.google_analytics.google_analytics_fact` as GA,
   UNNEST(GA.hits) as hits
 WHERE (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) WHERE index=3) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Subqueries on arrays are fine because BQ works highly parallelized. Cross joins are way more problematic. Having customer id in a hits custom dimension is a tough choice.